# Was the second part of the Tanya ("The Gateway of Unity and Belief") initially released together with the first part?

Tags: history, jewish-books, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, publications

Was the second book in the Tanya, Shaar Yichud vEmunah ("The Gateway of Unity and Belief") originally published alongside the first book?

Comment: Why might you think it wasn't? Why do you want to know this? Please edit to fill out your question.

Answer (score 3):

When the Tanya was first published in book form (1796), the first 2 sections were released. In a later printing (1806), the Baal HaTanya added a version of the 3rd section (it was later updated). The final two sections were added to the Tanya posthumously, by the Author's children. - [Starting from about minute 4 of this lecture](http://www.insidechassidus.org/media/Classes/TNYLCTRS/TNY_LECTURES_075_71.mp3).

Prior to its publishing in book form it was released pamphlet form, but I'm not sure how that process went.

There is a "*tradition handed down by chassidim that the Alter Rebbe originally intended to reverse the current order, with this second part of Tanya appearing first, as Part I, and the fifty-three chapters of the first part becoming Part II*" - [Lessons in Tanya, Intro to Shaar Hayichud VeHaEmunah](http://www.chabadps.com/m/dailystudy//?tDate=5/22/2015&type=tanya)

Comment: Among potential sources for this, one could point to HaYom Yom for 20 Kislev.